# Given a trained environment, how do I evaluate the policy at a specific state?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray

I've trained a Ray-RLlib PPOTrainer on a custom environment.  How do I evaluate the policy at a specific state?

Full example:

```
from ray.rllib.agents.ppo import PPOTrainer
from cust_env.envs import CustEnv
from ray.tune.logger import pretty_print

ray.init()
config = ppo.DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy()
config["num_workers"] = 2
config["eager"] = False
config["output"] = 'tmp/debug/'
trainer = PPOTrainer(config=config, env=TravelEnv)

# Can optionally call trainer.restore(path) to load a checkpoint.

for i in range(101):

   result = trainer.train()

   if i % 10 == 0:
       print(pretty_print(result))
```

Is there a way, something like the following, in which I can return the optimal action at a given state?

```
policy = trainer.get_policy()
optimal_action_at_state_S = policy.get_optimal_action(S)
```

The function `policy.compute_actions( )` appears to return a random sample from the stochastic policy, not an optimal action.

Comment: If you edited your answer to include a minimal code example to reproduce the behavior you want, including imports, you are more likely to get a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

According the Ray developer I got in touch with via the Ray-dev Google group, the only way to accomplish this currently is to use a custom action distribution in which the variance is set to zero.  He did note, however, that an improved interface will be added soon.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just to complement, as i bumped into this thread: option is available now
https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/_modules/ray/rllib/policy/policy.html
e.g. compute_actions -> set explore=False to obtain deterministic action